# ICMP - How to send a timestamp and netmask request?

Tags: icmp

How can I submit a ICMP request for timestamp and netmask request to a host without using NMAP?

Is it possible to generate a terminal / command line request with a tool like hping3 or any native Linux / Windows tool?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible using hping3. Here is an example for creating this request for dest IP 10.0.0.19:

Timestamp request: `sudo hping3 10.0.0.19 --icmp --icmp-ts -V`

Address mask request: `sudo hping3 -C 17 10.0.0.19`